# Does Platform::String^ bind directly to a const char[]?

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx

When creating a `Platform::String^` out of a `const char[]` string; ie

```
auto platformString = ref new Platform::String("MyString");
```

Does it bind directly to the compile time `const char[N]` string or does it allocate a copy to reference to?

Comment: @EdChum that's not C++/CLI, but C++/CX. Yeah, go figure why they created yet another syntax...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Jesus, I thought they stopped at C++/CLI! Sorry if this is dumb, is the clue here in the namespace and/or use of auto?

Comment: @EdChum there are two clues: the use of `ref new` instead of `gcnew` (I guess `gcnew` wouldn't be appropriate since C++/CX isn't garbage-collected but reference-counted instead), and the use of `Platform::String^` instead of `System::String^` for C++/CLI. `auto` is supported in C++/CLI also.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Huh as if C++ wasn't complicated enough already, thanks for the quick tutorial will lookout for this in future when retagging

Answer (score 1):

It takes a copy - it has to, since the lifetime of the `Platform::String^` is determined by ref-count, not by normal C++ lifetime rules.

```
auto greeting = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(20);
wcscpy_s(greeting.get(), 20, L"Hello, World");
auto s = ref new Platform::String(greeting.get());
greeting.reset();

// Still works, even though the original string is gone
OutputDebugString(s->Data());
```

If you look at the file **vccorlib.h** in your VC include directory (eg **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include**) then you will see the constructor that takes `const ::default::char16* __strArg` eventually calls [`WindowsCreateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br224630(v=vs.85).aspx) which takes a copy.

Comment: I updated the question to make clear I was talking about a compile time string.

Comment: That is a `const char*`; you can't overload based on literal-ness of the string.
    void foo(const char* s);
    void foo(const char s[]);

    error C2535: 'void foo(const char *)' : member function already defined or declared